# How to change OS X Lion DPI?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

How to change OS X Lion DPI?
I've just switch to Lion and I want the text size (every where) bigger, 125% big is OK, I tried many ways like:

- Quartz Debug - UI Resolution
- the "defaults write -g ..." command in Terminal

But they all DOESN'T WORK...

the only working method is change 1440*900 to 1280*800, but the screen performance is so bad.

Is there any other way please?

Comment: You just switched to Lion....?

Comment: yes, I just switched to lion from win7..

Comment: I'll update mt. lion next week, cause I want to experience lion for a few days ^_^

Answer (score 0):

They don't do arbitrary scaling anymore; the only option is to enable (with Quartz Debug) HiDPI display modes, to log out and log back in, and then use System Preferences to access the new HiDPI screen resolutions (Displays panel).